# pppd, docker, socat and permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, socat, pppd

We have an [Ubuntu 20.04] Docker image, used as part of a test system, in which I need to run `pppd` (to test a dial-up connection), where `pppd`  is connected to the physical modem via a `socat` loop.  My problem is that, when the [non-root] user of the Docker container (let's call the user `usera`) executes `pppd` (which is `setuid`, that part works fine), `pppd` is unable to access the device that the *same* *user* has set up just a moment ago using `socat`. `usera` successfully executes:

`socat pty,link=/tmp/ppp0,echo=0,raw,b115200 pty,link=/tmp/tty0,echo=0,raw,b115200`

...which runs fine, where the Dockerfile has set up the permissions on `/tmp` as:

`chmod 1777 /tmp`

...i.e. `tmp` has permissions `drwxrwxrwt`.

The `socat` command-line successfully creates:

```
ls -l /tmp
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ubxlib ubxlib 10 Mar  8 15:33 ppp0 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ubxlib ubxlib 10 Mar  8 15:33 tty0 -> /dev/pts/2
```

...but when `usera` then executes `pppd` to connect to one end of the loop, we get:

```
pppd /tmp/ppp0 115200 passive debug local nodetach
pppd: Couldn't stat /tmp/ppp0: Permission denied
```

If, instead, `usera` knows the `/dev/pts/x` that `socat` just created, rather than using the link through `/tmp/ppp0`, then `pppd` works:

```
pppd /dev/pts/1 115200 passive debug local nodetach
using channel 1
Using interface ppp0
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/1
...
```

How do I make `pppd` work with the link that `socat` provides, under the `usera` user, rather than `usera` having to know what `socat` has done?

For completeness, the permissions of `pppd` are `-rwsr-xr-x`.  `sudo` not an option here as this is inside a Docker container run via SSH by Jenkins, so there is no TTY/responder for a password.

Comment: It seems that setting `sudo sysctl fs.protected_symlinks=0` in the host Linux system (this seems to be something that must be set in the underlying file system, it is not something that Docker can do) fixes the problem.  Question is, is that wise?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that I needed to set `sudo sysctl fs.protected_symlinks=0` in the host Linux system (set persistently in `/usr/lib/sysctl.d/protect-links.conf`).  I will leave it up to the reader as to whether this is a *wise* thing to do or not, but for the purposes of our test system it is fine.